What is wrong with my simulation?
I am trying to design a isolated power supply with feedback control and I'm getting this error. I changed the initial timepoints and it did not simulate.



Whatever about the simulation error, you have a major design error: you have grounded both the input and output of a bridge rectifier. D4 is shorted out.

so unground D4.

Do you really want C1 to be 2 farads?

High side forward? Try a few of and Mohm to ground from M1 source. Try alternate solver.

If you start external DC supply voltages at 0 V, do you still get the error? Hit "a" in the schematic to bring up the configure analysis dialog, and you'll see a check box for this option. You might need to change V2 so that there is a non-zero time delay between Vinital and Von. Right click V2 and change Tdelay from 0 to something like 1m.

LTSpice and microcap sometimes have problems with high-side MOSFETs driving inductors. They come up with the same timestep problem but, there is no need to use a high-side MOSFET in an isolated supply. Use a low-side MOSFET instead by repositioning L5: -

